# KSH replacing string after string match

Tags: regex, awk, sed, ksh

My first time on Stack:

I'm doing a pattern match as follows. $VAR1 in this case is "/usr/lib/sendmail". The variable is read in from a separate file using a while loop.

```
cat /etc/rc.tcpip |grep -w "^start[[:blank:]]${VAR1}"
```

I want to "comment the line" (#) at the beginning of the match. I'm sure it's sed but I just can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

So existing line:

```
start /usr/lib/sendmail "$src_running" "-bd -q${qpi}"
```

desired result:

```
# start /usr/lib/sendmail "$src_running" "-bd -q${qpi}"
```

Comment: You have a UUOC in there: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html.  `cat $FILE | grep $PATTERN` is unnecessary.  You can simply do `grep $PATTERN $FILE` or `grep $PATTERN < $FILE`.

Comment: BashFAQ #21, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021, is well worth reading. (Yes, it _does_ explicitly apply to ksh).

Comment: The line beginning *after* the match, or the one beginning *with* the match? Your examples clearly seem to show the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed '\|^start[[:blank:]]'"$VAR1"'|s/^/# /' /etc/rc.tcpip
```

You need `\|` as your var has / in it. If you sed accepts `-i` you can put the result in the same file.

Normally the `sed` command would take the form:

```
/pattern1/s/pattern2/replacement/
```

where pattern1 selects a line to apply the substitute (`s`) to, pattern2 is what
to match, and replacement is what to replace the match by. In your case pattern1 contains the slash char `/` so to use it in pattern1 it would need to be escaped with `\`. However the slashes are inside $VAR1, so we would need to edit $VAR1 to replace every `/` with `\/`.

Instead it is simpler to use an alternative delimiter instead of /, just for /pattern1/. The syntax for this is a little bizarre and non-symmetric:

```
\|pattern1|s/pattern2/replacement/
```

The `\` at the start of the line says the next char is an alternative delimiter. I chose `|`, but another char not in pattern1 could do just as well, eg

```
\;pattern1;s/pattern2/replacement/
```

Comment: Thank you... This does work. However, putting code in my script I don't fully understand will "bite" me eventually. So, why does the "\" escape occur in the beginning before the "|" and not directly in front of the variable. I understand what it's needed for but don't understand the placement. Sorry for the extra question, but I truly need understand how it function. Thank you!!

Comment: @PeteNMeyburg I added an explanation